# Why _kbhit() freeze the thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2012

I want to know why _kbhit() in loop doesnt allow to work thread, in a code below there must be an output to the screen "Test!", but it doesnt happen. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <process.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

void Thread(void *par)
{
        while (true)
        {
            cout<<"Test!"<<endl;
        };
} 

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{ 
    _beginthread( Thread, 0, NULL);
    while(!_kbhit());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Neither `_kbhit()` nor `_beginthread()` are part of the C++ standard, and interaction between the two is not well-defined. All threads might be blocked until a key is hit, for all we know.

Comment: This program works for me. Spams "Test!" over and over until I push a key.

Comment: GManNickG . What environment do you use?

Comment: Yeah you right, well i use Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2012 and when i run this program with ctrl+f5 it not printing, if i run the exe file of debug version it going smoothly. Strange.

Comment: @Timur, in that case, can you open Task Manager (or its equivalent on Windows 8, which I hope exists) and check the CPU load to verify your program is actually running full tilt? If it is the case, then your worker thread has an output problem (maybe it cannot write to `cout`). Otherwise, it might be a locking problem due to `_beginthread()`, `_kbhit()`, or the combination of both on your platform.

Comment: Also: try `cout << "Test!" << endl << flush;`.  The buffering may be keeping you from seeing anything in some cases.

Comment: @WanderingLogic: According to §27.7.3.8 [ostream.manip] ¶1 of C++11 draft N3376, `endl` "calls `os.put(os.widen('\n'))`, then `os.flush()`", so `endl` implicitly calls `flush`; there is no need to do it manually.

Comment: My CPU usage is 99% and you right the cout isn`t working thread is working fine i checked with continuos variable increase. So what does it mean, can i somehow fix this?

Comment: @Timur, I don't know if it can be fixed, but in your situation I would check `cout.rdstate()` just in case, and replace the `while (!kbhit());` busy-wait loop with a call to `sleep()` to get it out of the equation.

Comment: @TimurKukharskiy: Are you, by any chance running on a single-core, single CPU system?

Comment: He must be if he gets 99% cpu load.  That's pretty unusual, smells like an ARM core.

Comment: Well yes i have a single core processor Sempron 2.7 (i know it`s old) and after all i checked the exe programm that i build on my computer on another one and it`s run perfectly from cmd.exe. And when i run on my computer through a cmd.exe i have no output unless i close and open the window of programm, and then it works. So this must be somehow kind of a glich that is related to my platform. A need to buy a new computer, problem solved. :)